# To Squanch or not to Squanch: That is the Squanch

Tags: cipher, language

I've been thinking about Squanchics (how we Squanch words) and language in general.

I really Squanch that it matters *not* if Squanch uses words we are familiar with when they are Squanching or writing. We can figure out what they mean Squanchively. It only takes a few clues.

Squanch this for an example: If someone told you that they love it when clowns juggle while riding a *squanch*, would you know what they were Squanching about? Squanch'd bet money that you would. There is Squanch more adaptable on God's Squanch earth than the human mind.

Have you ever Squanched how Squanch you actually Squanch every word in a sentence? You Squanch have to be a rocket Squanchist to realize that you actually Squanch a Squanch percentage of them.

By now, you should have Squanched out what the Squanching, basic idea of this post is, right?

Can you Squanch it in four words?

<sub>Bonus: Can you tell which [animated TV series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=igkap_uLzDw&feature=youtu.be) I've been watching?</sub>

Comment: I believe the correct answer has already been posted, but as for your bonus question rot13(Lbh'ir orra jngpuvat gur Fzhesf.)

Comment: I'm going with the bonus as: (ROT13)Evpx naq zbegl

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Filling in the squanches with their implied meanings:

> I've been thinking about **semantics** (how we **understand** words) and language in general.
>
>  I really **believe** that it matters not if **someone** uses words we are familiar with when they are **talking** or writing. We can figure out what they mean **intuitively**. It only takes a few clues.
>
>  **Take** this for an example: If someone told you that they love it when clowns juggle while riding a **unicycle**, would you know what they were **talking** about? **I**'d bet money that you would. There is **nothing** more adaptable on God's **green** earth than the human mind.
>
>  Have you ever **wondered** how **often** you actually **read** every word in a sentence? You **don't** have to be a rocket **scientist** to realize that you actually **ignore*** a **small*** percentage of them.
>
>  By now, you should have **figured** out what the **underlying**, basic idea of this post is, right?
>
>  Can you **name** it in four words?
>
>  <sub>The ones marked with asterisks stolen from @gabbo1092 :)</sub>

When you

> Take the first letter from each word

It reads

> **SUBSTITUTING WORDS IS FUN**

Title:

> To **be** or not to **be**: That is the **question**.  
>  Which produces **BBQ** :)

Comment: Plus one for the first two squanches! I've edited my original question from **three** to **four**. Three was from an earlier draft. :(  Does this help?

Comment: Possible last few words rot13:(vtaber, fznyy, znxvat gur ynfg gjb jbeqf vf sha (fgvyy pna'g svaq fbzrguvat sbe h naq a gubhtu))

Comment: @gabbo1092 I think you're right!

Comment: @jafe the last word could be anzr

Comment: @El-Guest great minds... was just typing that in :)

Comment: OK, you'll get the squanch. I really enjoy seeing collective collaboration like this! Makes me go all squanchy inside.

Comment: There is some irony in the squanch that for about 1/3 of `squanch`es I thought they were obviously something else.

Comment: I believe the cartoon is rot13(Evpx naq Zbegl) but I haven't watched it in a while and it may be a reference used in one or two eps only

Comment: The one relating to the clown was giving me a lot of trouble.

Answer (score 4):

Bonus

> You've been watching a lot of [Rick and Morty](http://rickandmorty.wikia.com/wiki/Squanchy) lately like me

Answer (score 3):

My attempt at deciphering the paragraph:

> I've been thinking about (phon)ics (how we (learn?) words) and language in general. 
> I really (think) that it matters not if (one) uses words we are familiar with when they are (speak)ing or writing. We can figure out what they mean (relat)ively. It only takes a few clues. 
> (Take) this for an example: If someone told you that they love it when clowns juggle while riding a (unicycle), would you know what they were (talk)ing about? (I)'d bet money that you would. There is (few?) more adaptable on God's (great) earth than the human mind. 
> Have you ever (wonder/notic)ed how Squanch you actually Squanch every word in a sentence? You (would) have to be a rocket (scient)ist to realize that you actually (read) a (small) percentage of them. 
> By now, you should have (figured)ed out what the Squanching, basic idea of this post is, right? Can you (describe) it in three words?

My answer:

> Based on what I think this post means my three word answer would be: Understanding replacement words.

Answer (score 2):

I’m really unsure about this, but is it the

> The redundancy in the English language?

Three words?

> Context in English?

Explanation:

> You can figure out the meaning of most of the Squanch words just from context